# Execute immediate and missing invalid option

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

The procedure is for cloning a table. It receives the names of the two tables in parameters, and when called it should clone the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLONE_TABLE(
table_source VARCHAR2,
table_destination  VARCHAR2)
is
begin
execute immediate 'create table ' || table_destination || 'as select* from ' 
|| table_source;
end;
```

But when i call the procedure, I receive error `ORA-00922: Missing or invalid option`.

```
BEGIN
CLONE_TABLE('example','example_new')
END
```

I don't realise what's the problem and how should I fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Writing dynamic SQL is hard, because what should be compilation errors become runtime errors. It is therefore crucial to develop a cool eye when looking at your own code. You have to be the compiler.

It helps to assemble the statement as a variable first. That way you can display the statement in the case of error, which makes debugging easier.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLONE_TABLE(
    table_source VARCHAR2,
    table_destination  VARCHAR2)
is
    stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
    stmt := 'create table ' || table_destination || 'as select* from ' 
|| table_source;
    execute immediate stmt;
exception
    when others then
         dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
         raise;
end;
```

If you had done that if would have been obvious that you were missing a space in front of the `as`. So your executed statement was this:

```
 create table example_newas select* from example
```

The space between `select` and `*` is optional, but code looks better with one.

Comment: Thanks for exception handling part. I was not exactly sure on how to code it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 problem and couple of suggestions for your code.

1. Missing space before `as select...`
2. Calling of procedure, use `exec` or `call` statements.

   Suggestions:

   - Make sure to do proper error handling (so if a table doesn't exists, or if a table destination already exists, you should get proper return message.
   - Also separate each keyword with space as other answers suggested, like between `select` and `*`. But not doing it will not give you error.

     ```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLONE_TABLE(
     table_source VARCHAR2,
     table_destination  VARCHAR2)
     is
     begin
     execute immediate 'create table ' || table_destination || ' as select* from ' 
     || table_source;
     end;

     EXEC CLONE_TABLE('example','example_new')
     ```

Answer (score 1):

There is should be one space before `as select..` and in between `select` and `*` near `select*...`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLONE_TABLE(
table_source VARCHAR2,
table_destination  VARCHAR2)
is
begin
execute immediate 'create table ' || table_destination || ' as select * from ' || table_source;
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8  

Procedure created.

SQL> create table example(id number);

Table created.

SQL> exec CLONE_TABLE('example','example_new');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLONE_TABLE (table_source         VARCHAR2,
                                         table_destination    VARCHAR2)
IS
v_sql varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

 v_sql:=  'create table '
      || table_destination
      || ' as select * from '
      || table_source;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;

END;
```

The best way to handle issue like you got is to display first what you are trying to execute immediate. You get to know your fault.